# Video.js, tap video on mobile to play/pause

Tags: javascript, mobile, video.js

firstly I don't know the logic or syntax of javascript- I just grab code and maybe swap out some values, so as much hand holding as you can provide in your answer is greatly appreciated. I just want my video on mobile devices to pause on tap/resume playing on tap, like with YouTube. I’m currently using CDN for the default css and js files, then I have some skin customization in my css, and my own local js file with the below code. I just need to know what code to add, and where to add it- thanks in advance!

```
$(function(){
  var $refreshButton = $('#refresh');
  var $results = $('#css_result');

  function refresh(){
    var css = $('style.cp-pen-styles').text();
    $results.html(css);
  }

  refresh();
  $refreshButton.click(refresh);

  // Select all the contents when clicked
  $results.click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a "touchstart" event on the container of the Video. For example, if the video is inside  then:

```
jQuery(function(){
  var $refreshButton = jQuery('#refresh');
  var $results = jQuery('#css_result');

  function refresh(){
    var css = jQuery('style.cp-pen-styles').text();
    $results.html(css);
  }

  refresh();
  $refreshButton.click(refresh);

  // Select all the contents when clicked
  $results.click(function(){
    jQuery(this).select();
  });

  jQuery( '.video' ).on('touchstart', function(){
      if (player.userActive() === true) 
      {
        player.userActive(false);
      } 
      else 
      {
        player.userActive(true);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bu could you elaborate a bit please? I assume this code goes into my local .js doc with the code I'd posted above? And by "container" of the video you mean its div container in html?